# web browsing(client side functionality) in ie slow over remote desktop

Tags: windows-server-2008, remote-desktop, internet-explorer

**Is there anything that can be done to speed up IE, browsing on localhost, on a remote desktop connection?** I know the obvoius answer is to just use the browser on your own machine, but it would be a little easier for me in my current situation to just speed it up somehow if possible. We have QA testing a suite of tools that gets regularly updated on a windows server 2008 r2 machine. because they are already remoted in to that machine doing the testing, they find it easier to use the browser on that machine to test the web portion on localhost. The problem is that IE sems to really drag when doing this. Even the hovers on fairly simple pages seem to be delayed in popping up, but some of the javascript code seems to REALLY drag. Neither of these seem to be issues if you navigate to the site directly. Is there anything we can do to increase the browser performance when using remote desktop to a windows server machine, or should I just tell everyone to use ther browsers on their own machine to navigate to the site?

I know there are variables that would way into this performance like strength of connection, server resource(they are getting hammered right now), and the fact that our QA team is on the other side of the planet, but I thought I would hit up the stack echange since i couldnt find a good solution online elsewhere.

I recognize that this might be better suited for a different stack exchange site, if you know where i should move this question please tell me in the comments.

Comment: Need some hard numbers to begin troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the easiest would be just to use the browser on your own machines, however, have you triad any other browsers (such as chrome or Firefox?) I do find them to work much faster in general.

Comment: we do some cross browser compatibility testing, but most clients use ie, so thats what we are pretty much stuck with

Comment: I can't really help without more information. I'd just stick with using the local browser. It's by far the simplest method in this situation.